# Dropdown values in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a two dropdown's with the list of items 2 and 6 respectively. When i select first dropdown item, the list of items in second one will be 6 and when i select other value in first dropdown, the list of items should be 5 in second dropdown,

Please find the code here:

```
<select id="firstdropdown">
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Testing</option>
</select>
<select id="seconddropdown">
    <option value="1">test1</option>
    <option value="2">test2</option>
    <option value="3">test3</option>
    <option value="4">test4</option>
    <option value="5">test5</option>
    <option value="6">test6</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone suggest me a solution in jquery or javascript?

Comment: Do you mean you want to select the items with values `5` or `6`, or you want there to be `5` or `6` items available in the second select? Your question is not clear. Also, SO questions should include any code you have written yourself to find a solution.

Comment: When i select 'Test' all the values in second dropdown should be listed and when i select 'Testing', only 5 values should be listed in second dropdown

Answer (score 6):

You can do this way, I assumed you want to show / hide `last` item. you can change it to your desired by giving `index`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tu858/)**

```
$('#firstdropdown').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "2")
        $('#seconddropdown option:eq(5)').hide();
    else
        $('#seconddropdown option:eq(5)').show();
});​
```

Comment: Thanks. But i could not find any difference. I need to hide the 3rd item in the list, when i select the other item value in the first dropdown. Suggest me a solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you are removing a item for a second option of first drop down

```
 $("#firstdropdown").change(function() {
    if(this.value === "2") $("#seconddropdown option:last").remove();
    //here you are just removing last item    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
$("#firstdropdown").change(function() {
    if(this.value === "1") $("#seconddropdown").val("6");
    else $("#seconddropdown").val("5");
})
```

---

**EDIT :** added a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/scaillerie/WGhLA/

Comment: I think OP wants list of 6 items or 5 items for seconddropdown

Answer (score 0):

If you need to hide any item in the dropdown, you just need to change the index of 'eq'

```
 $('#firstdropdown').change(function(){
     if($(this).val() == "2")
        $('#seconddropdown option:eq(3)').hide(); // change the index of 'eq' 
     else
        $('#seconddropdown option:eq(3)').show();
  });​
```

Comment: Thanks. But this code does not works for me.Suggest me some solution